# How to round numbers in a table?

Tags: tables, math-mode, siunitx, numprint

Please excuse me if my question is poorly worded as I am a beginner. I have a table in Latex whose data was originally generated using Python. I then used tablesgenerator.com to properly format the data and to convert to Latex code.

It all worked well. However, now I need to round the numbers in the table (one column to 3 decimal places and rest of the columns to 2 decimal places). I found a few resources online including previous questions asked on this community. However, I was not able to implement the ideas successfully (tried using numprint and siunitx). I would much appreciate it if anyone could help me do this.

Here is an example:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[]
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|rrrr|rr|rr|rr|rr|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Object}          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Scenario 1}                                                                                 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Scenario 2}                                                                               & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Scenario 3}                                                                             \\ \cline{2-13} 
                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1}                 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 2}              & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 1}                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 2}              & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 1}                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 2}              \\ \cline{2-13} 
                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Stat 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Stat 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Stat 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Stat 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Stat 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Stat 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Stat 2} \\ \hline
$a$                   & 49.143                  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.81}     & 49.143                  & 49.143                          & 18.121                  & 41.143                         & 49.143                  & 47.143                         & 23.143                   & 49.143                         & 49.143                   & 59.143                         \\
$b$      & 52.411                  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0.231}    & 49.143                  & 49.143                          & 18.121                  & 41.143                         & 49.143                  & 47.143                         & 23.143                   & 49.143                         & 49.143                   & 59.143                         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table]

To be specific, how would I round all the Stat 1 columns to 2 decimal places and round all the Stat 2 columns to 3 decimal places (which is already the case in the table above, but assuming this weren't already the case)?

Note: my actual tables have hundreds of rows, so manually editing the numbers wouldn't be an option.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use `siunitx` and its `S` column type. It defines a `table-auto-round`  key (which takes the value false by default),and add $0s if necessary  to fit  the number of prescribed decimal digits (e.g. in the leftmost Stat 2 column, 0.81 would be replaced with 0.810. Further, all decimal dots will be vertically aligned.

Comment: Do not use `adjustbox` in order to make a table fit into the available space. This will lead to inconsistent font sizes and line widths throughout your documenr.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for the warning. How would you suggest I shrink the table to fit to the page width? (landscape mode)

Comment: That entirely depends on how much space there is available. If you want a more specific advice, please prepare a complete and compilable minimal working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could use `siunitx`'s `table-auto-round` option in combination with `table-format` in order to determine the number of decimal places to which the numbers in your table are rounded and aligned.

I also simplified the code by removing unnecessary `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` commands and added missing vertical lines in the header rows back in. Lastly, I removed `adjustbox` and instead reduced the font size and the value of `\tabcolsep` in order to make the table less wide.

Additionally, I added a `booktabs`-based version of your table that uses no vertical lines and some horizontal lines with improved spacing. Slightly altering the header of the first column by abbreviation the long word also makes it possible to use a slightly larger font size while still keeping the roughly at the same width as in the first example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.75pt}
\sisetup{table-auto-round}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{6}{S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.3]|}}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Scenario 1} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Scenario 2} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Scenario 3} \\ \cline{2-13} 
 Object & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 1}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 2}              
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 2}              
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 2} \\ \cline{2-13} 
  & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} 
  & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} 
  & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} \\ \hline
$a$   & 49.143 & 0.81  & 49.143 & 49.143 & 18.121 & 41.143 & 49.143 & 47.143 & 23.143 & 49.143 & 49.143 & 59.143 \\
$b$   & 52.411 & 0.231 & 49.143 & 49.143 & 18.121 & 41.143 & 49.143 & 47.143 & 23.143 & 49.143 & 49.143 & 59.143 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\small
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.25pt}
\sisetup{table-auto-round}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{6}{S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.3]}@{}}
\toprule
 Obj. & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Scenario 1} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Scenario 2} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Scenario 3} \\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}              
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}              
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2} \\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}  \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13}
  & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} 
  & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} 
  & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} & {Stat 1} & {Stat 2} \\ \midrule
$a$   & 49.143 & 0.81  & 49.143 & 49.143 & 18.121 & 41.143 & 49.143 & 47.143 & 23.143 & 49.143 & 49.143 & 59.143 \\
$b$   & 52.411 & 0.231 & 49.143 & 49.143 & 18.121 & 41.143 & 49.143 & 47.143 & 23.143 & 49.143 & 49.143 & 59.143 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```